# Date/Time Scatter Graph Python Matplotlib

Tags: python, date, matplotlib

I have a number of unix timestamps that I wish to plot only the days, as in Monday-Sunday on the x axis. My data only contains data for Saturday and Sunday but I still want to show the other days along the x axis. How can I go about doing this?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that with matplotlib. See [skip dates where there is no data](http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#skip-dates-where-there-is-no-data).